# `ArrayInput` but only for a single item

Tags: react-admin

The following snippet inside an Edit context creates an Array as listed below.

```
import { ArrayInput, SimpleFormIterator, DateInput, TextInput } from 'react-admin';

<ArrayInput source="backlinks">
    <SimpleFormIterator>
        <DateInput source="date" />
        <TextInput source="url" />
    </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

JSON:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "backlinks": [
        {
            "date": "2012-08-10T00:00:00.000Z",
            "url": "http://example.com/foo/bar.html",
        },
        {
            "date": "2012-08-14T00:00:00.000Z",
            "url": "https://blog.johndoe.com/2012/08/12/foobar.html",
        }
   ]
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same for a single item? Something like a reference field but without the feature to select an existing item. Rather the user should need to create one like in the example above.

Comment: if the answer is not what you're asking for, you could try to clarify your question or if it sufficient mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a special input component, `react-admin` inputs let you edit nested objects by default by specifing the path in the `source` prop

```
<DateInput source="backlink.date" />
<TextInput source="backlink.url" />
```

Hope this solves the problem.